# "Erfassen" and "verstehen"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

What is the difference between *erfassen* and *verstehen*? Both mean to comprehend, but in what context is *erfassen* used?

> 1. Ich ***verstehe*** den Satz sehr gut.
> 2. Ich ***erfasse*** den Satz sehr gut.

Comment: it's interesting that there's a similar distinction in the English language: *verstehen* is derived from *stehen*, ie *to stand* and we get to the English equivalent *to understand*; now, *erfassen* is derived from *fassen*, which translates as *to grasp*, which can also used with the meaning of mentally grasping a concept and thus *erfassen*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Verstehen* is the most general *to understand* and you basically do that with facts and rules.

*Erfassen* is shifted toward a grasping something in its complete  scope. You could maybe think of it as *to fathom*.
So I think you can *erfassen* something without really understanding it.

> Du willst also nackt zum Nordpol laufen? - Du hast es erfasst.
>
> So you want to walk naked to the North Pole?  - You got it.

No understanding implied.

Answer (score 2):

*Verstehen* is the more general term, as illustrated by the following example:

You can fail to understand a spoken sentence because you did not hear it correctly, or because you failed to grasp its meaning; *verstehen* covers both cases, *erfassen* just the latter.

It's interesting that the images used in the German and English language are quite close to each other:

- *verstehen* is derived from *stehen*, ie *to stand* with the corresponding *to understand*
- *erfassen* is derived from *fassen*, ie *to grasp* which can mean either of these two words

In the second case, the correspondence is not perfect, though: First, *begreifen* is probably even closer etymologically, but I'd translate that as *to comprehend*. Second, *fassen* can also mean *to catch*. *Erfassen* cannot be used in the sense of

> I didn't catch that.

though, but rather

> This catches its meaning nicely.

Note that

> Ich erfasse den Satz sehr gut.

isn't really something a native speaker would say (at least I wouldn't).

Comment: Richtig, eher würde man *die Bedeutung* eines Satzes erfassen, oder den Grund, warum ein Satz gesagt wurde, usw.